# Redmine add watchers after bug creation

Tags: bug-tracking, redmine

I have been trying out Redmine to see if I like it better than mantis.  However, I am wondering if it possible to modify watchers of a bug after bug creation.  As a project manager, when I create a bug, I can select users to have watch a bug, but after I create it, I don't see a way to edit this list.  Does Redmine have support for modifying the list of users watch a bug?  If so where?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Of course you can edit this list - if you have the necessary permission, there should be the list of watchers at the right hand side of the issue's detail page, with a link to *add* watchers opening a dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was looking in the wrong place; I didn't notice the option in the side bar.

Comment: Mybe it would be good to change the position of it. I is not intuitive. Me and my colleagues ware not seeng it.

Comment: Now that I know where to look, I don't understand how I could not notice it. And yes, it is somewhat counter-intuitive that it isn't visualized in the same way like when you create the ticket.

Comment: Hah I just had this same problem, I guess this design is pretty confusing